# Deriving $dy/dx = 2\cos x/\cos y$ given $\sin y=2\sin x$

Tags: trigonometry, implicit-differentiation

My original question is to find the second derivative of $\sin y=2\sin x$

I derived it once got $2\cos x/\cos y$ which was correct but the second time did not get $3\sec^2y\tan y$ which is the answer.

Im not sure where I've gone wrong, please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(y)}$$
Recall the quotient rule, then the second derivative will be
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}&=2\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\cos(x)}{\cos(y)}\\
&=2\frac{-\sin(x)\cos(y)+\sin(y)\frac{dy}{dx}\cos(x)}{\cos^2(y)}\\
&=\frac{-\sin(y)\cos(y)+4\tan(y)\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(y)}
\end{align}$$
We know that
$$\sin(y)=2\sin(x)$$
Then 
$$\sqrt{1-\cos^2(y)}=2\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x)}$$
$$1-\cos^2(y)=4(1-\cos^2(x))$$
$$\cos^2(x)=\frac{3+\cos^2(y)}{4}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}&=\frac{-\sin(y)\cos(y)+\tan(y)(3+\cos^2(y))}{\cos^2(y)}\\
&=\frac{-\sin(y)\cos(y)+3\tan(y)+\sin(x)\cos(y)}{\cos^2(y)}\\
&=3\sec^2(y)\tan(y)
\end{align}$$

Comment: Ahh okay! This makes a lot of sense, i was wondering that when you manipulated the identity how you knew which root to take? Like why did you do the positive root instead of the negative?

Comment: I am not sure if I totally understand your question. It doesn't really matter whether I take positive or negative root. When I square both sides, they will become positive.